# Reverse LISP list in place

Tags: lisp

I would like to write a function that reverses the elements of a list, but it should happen in place (that is, don't create a new reversed list).

Something like:

```
>> (setq l ' (a b c d))
((a b c d)
>> (rev l)
(d c b a)
>> l
(d c b a)
```

What flags should I follow to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not difficult to implement this (ignoring fault cases).  The keys are to use `(setf cdr)` to reuse a given cons cell and not to lose the reference to the prior cdr.

```
(defun nreverse2 (list)
  (recurse reving ((list list) (rslt '()))
    (if (not (consp list))
        rslt
        (let ((rest (cdr list)))
          (setf (cdr list) rslt)
          (reving rest list)))))

(defmacro recurse (name args &rest body)
  `(labels ((,name ,(mapcar #'car args) ,@body))
     (,name ,@(mapcar #'cadr args))))
```

[edit] As mentioned in a comment, to do this truly in-place (and w/o regard to consing):

```
(defun reverse-in-place (l)
  (let ((result l))
    (recurse reving ((l l) (r (reverse l))
      (cond ((not (consp l)) result)
            (else (setf   (car l) (car r))
                  (reving (cdr l) (cdr r)))))))

> (defvar l '(1 2 3))
> (reverse-in-place l))
(3 2 1)
> l
(3 2 1)
```

Comment: That recycles the cons cells (so it's appropriately called `nreverse2` (n for non-consing)), but it doesn't reverse the list _in place_.  The cons that is the head of the original list is not the head of the reversed list.  E.g., `(let ((l (list 1 2 3))) (nreverse2 l) l)` produces `(1)`.

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at `nreverse` which will modify the list in place (see [HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_revers.htm)).

As per the comments, do note the comments that @Barmar made and this bit from the spec:

> For nreverse, sequence might be destroyed and re-used to produce the result. The result might or might not be identical to sequence. Specifically, when sequence is a list, nreverse is permitted to setf any part, car or cdr, of any cons that is part of the list structure of sequence.

Comment: Note that you need to assign it back to the variable, e.g. `(setq l (nreverse l))`. It reuses the original list elements, but a different cons could be the head of the result.